# FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL not working / Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, overlay

I am developing an application on Android. My application in essence is a call log. What I want is for my application to display three buttons above all other activities when the device receives an incomming call.

What I have right now is a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) which receives PHONE_STATE intents and when an incomming call is detected, an activity is started. The started activity contains the buttons I want to be displayed.

**When the OverlayActivity appears, all activities underneath stop receiving touch events, that is I can touch only the OverlayActivity. How do I make them receive the events?**

Right now inside my BroadCastReceiver I start the activity:

```
//PhonecallReceiver.java
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(myContext, OverlayActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra("phone_number", number);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

The actuall activity

```
//OverlayActivity.java:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    mLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null);
    wm.addView(mLayout, params);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ivan. There is no need to edit the question to give the solution. In fact it is better to create an answer to your own question giving details of what you did. This will help anybody coming to StackOverflow with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DJClayworh

Thanks for the tip :)

I managed to solve my problem by using the exam same code, but instead of an Activity, I used a Service. You just have to start the service to display the overlay. Here is an example:

```
public class OverlayService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private View layout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            // very important, this sends toush events to underlying views
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        // Layout gravity
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x = 0; params.y = 100;

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
             .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // Your overlay layout
        layout = li.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null;

        // This displays overlay on the screen
        windowManager.addView(layout, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Error will occur if this is missing.
        if (layout != null)
            windowManager.removeView(layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is partially incorrect and misleading. It actually has nothing to do with displaying from a service, but with the window flag: WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, Which you can define on an activity as well. Cheers.